# Can you re-use deleted Git branch names?

Tags: git, branch

If I create a Git branch named "foobar", do some work in it, merge it back into my development branch and then delete the foobar branch, can I create another branch at some future point with the same name "foobar" or will this confuse Git?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In git, a branch name is simply a pointer to a particular commit. Adding things to the branch simply moves that pointer to a new commit. Deleting the branch simply means deleting the pointer. If you re-create that same branch at some point in the future, you are just creating a new pointer, pointing to a different commit.

TL;DR: Yes, you can do this, and no, it will not confuse Git.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, no problem. Branch names are only for humans anyway. Git only cares about SHAs.

Answer (score 4):

You may reuse the branch name at any time, and *git* won't care.

You could easily confuse *yourself* though, so you should be somewhat careful here.  (I speak from experience :-) )

There's one other consideration: when you share work with other people by publishing commits from your repository or obtaining commits from theirs, you will generally do this by giving them your branch names, or looking at their branch names.  If you told Fred to look at your branch `foobar` last week, and then you deleted `foobar` and created a new and different `foobar` this week and Fred goes and gets your `foobar`, you are likely to confuse Fred, too.

Comment: Fred should not have an expectation that a branch is immutable. Even if it were the "same" branch, it's likely to move on the timeline at any time.

Comment: @dualmon: sure, but he (Fred) might well expect the branch to move only in "fast forward" fashion.  For instance, last time he fetched, his remote said that `dualmon/foobar` was commit `1cf97a3`, and this time `dualmon/foobar` doesn't even have `1cf97a3` in its history: how can this be?  One way it can be is that this foobar is unrelated to the previous foobar.  If everyone's agreed that this should happen now and then, it's not all that confusing, but it *is* something to consider.

Comment: Very true. Also can happen if foobar is rebased.